# Grails: Ajax response empty

Tags: ajax, grails

I want to change the layout when there is an ajax request. So I setup an Filter for that:

```
class AjaxFilters {

def filters = {
    ajaxify(controller: '*', action: '*') {
        after = { Map model ->


    if(model==null) {
        model = new HashMap()
    }

    // only intercept AJAX requests
    if (!request.xhr) {
        model.put("layout", "mainUsers")
        return true 
    }

    // find our controller to see if the action is ajaxified
    def artefact = grailsApplication
        .getArtefactByLogicalPropertyName("Controller", controllerName)
    if (!artefact) { return true }

    // check if our action is ajaxified
    def isAjaxified = artefact.clazz.declaredFields.find {
        it.name == 'ajaxify'
    } != null


    def ajaxified = isAjaxified ? artefact.clazz?.ajaxify : []
    if (actionName in ajaxified || '*' in ajaxified) {
        model.put("layout", "ajax")
        return false
    }
    return true
        }
    }
}
}
```

This creates a view model named "layout" which should define what layout to use.

Here is an example view which uses the layout model:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<meta name="layout" content="${layout}"/>
<title>Profile</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Edit Profile</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the controller:

```
class SettingsController {
def springSecurityService
static ajaxify = ["profile", "account"]

def profile() {
    User user = springSecurityService.currentUser

    UserProfile profile = UserProfile.findByUser(user)

    if(profile == null) {
        flash.error="Profile not found."
        return
    }

    [profile: profile, user: user]
}
}
```

A normal request works as expected, but when I try an ajax one the response is completly empty. Only headers are sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your `model.put("layout", "ajax")` you don't want to return `false` but rather `true`.  Returning `false` indicates the filter failed in some way and halts all further processing, which will result in an empty response being returned to the browser.  If you return `true`, the updated model will continue through the processing chain and be rendered in your gsp.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning true or false for ajax requests which will return blank. You should convert the model object as JSON using render function or convert the model object to JSON and return it.
You don't need to check if action is ajaxified; just return the JSON object.

Comment: I don't want to return JSON, I want to render the view as normal html